# Getting selected option value without postback/submit PHP

Tags: php

I'm trying to get select options from database that works for now, but I can't  get the selected value without submitting the `<form>`

```
<label for="NomEns">Choisir un enseignant: </label>
<select name="dd1" id="combo" class="form-control">
    <option value="" <?php if(!isset($_POST['NomEns']) || (isset($_POST['NomEns']) && empty($_POST['NomEns']))) { ?>selected<?php } ?>>--Select--</option>
<?php while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) { ?>
    <option value="<?php echo $row['NomEns']; ?>" <?php if(isset($_POST['NomEns']) && $_POST['NomEns'] == $row['NomEns']) { ?>selected<?php } ?>><?php echo $row['NomEns']; ?></option>
<?php } ?>
</select>
```

Comment: If you don't want to submit the form you need to use AJAX.

Comment: If you want selected value in front end you can get like 
     $('#dropDownId :selected').text();

Comment: Where do you want to read the value? If you don't send it in same way to the backend, you obviously can't handle it in the backend. So are you asking about a javascript solution? What do you want to do with the value? Can it be done on client side?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you need to use `onchange` event

```
$('select').on('change', function() {
    var value= this.value ;
    $.ajax({

        url:'action.php',
        type:'POST',
        data: { 
            'value':value
        },

        success: function(data) {
            alert(data);
        }
    });
})
```

And make file `action.php`

```
if(isset($_POST['value'])) {
    $username = $_POST['value'];
    //your database query
    $query=something;
    if ($query) {
        echo 'success';
    }
    else {
        echo 'something went wrong';
    }
}
```

Comment: I did this, but now I want to transfer this value to database
I will explain more, I have an upload page where the user has to choose the recipient and select a file and then after upload data gets saved in BDD

Comment: use ajax for that

Comment: I will start working with ajax as you said, thank you so much for the answer "answered!"

Comment: Accept answer please